# Where can I get FDMA Competition dataset?

Tags: dataset, tensor, tensorflow-datasets, huggingface-datasets, bigquery-public-datasets

I am working on malicious activity detection and am searching for the FDMA 2012 competition dataset. I have encountered difficulty accessing it, as SMU, which originally organized the competition, has marked the dataset as inactive on their website. I was not able to find any APIs either. Am I missing something? Could anyone please tell me how I can get my hands on it?

Thank you!